# How to shrink a layer in FramerJS

Tags: user-interface, framerjs

```
animationA = new Animation
layer: doc.canteen
properties:
    x: 400
    y: 1600
    opacity: 0.5
curve: "bezier-curve(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)"
```

here i tried using z value, it was scaled up. To scale down i thought we should use - value, then also it scaled up but in reverse. I want to scale it down. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To shrink a layer use the Scale property.

```
animationA = new Animation
    layer: doc.canteen
    properties:
        scale: .5 #Scales down to 50%
    curve: "bezier-curve(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)"
```

Here is an example: http://share.framerjs.com/4nxwdq04ar30/